# ogr2ogr ascii --> Shape

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr, ogr2ogr, ascii

I have plenty of Digital Terrain Model (DTM) data in ASCII format as *.txt files. Now I want to convert them into separate ESRI shapefiles as a batch.

Does anyone know how I can handle this issue?

Comment: To avoid creating massive Shapefiles, you should convert your DTM ASCII files to a raster data format (e.g. GeoTiff) using GDAL